# SQLiteException: no such column: ٢٠٦٦١٤٨ (code 1): Special character

Tags: android, sqlite

I have trouble with SQLite error: Caused by:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ٢٠٦٦١٤٨ (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE History SET unreadNum=? WHERE senderId = ٢٠٦٦١٤٨
```

And my code is:

```
public void resetHistoryMessageUnreadNum(Integer senderID) {
    openWrite();
    ContentValues result = new ContentValues();
    result.put(COLUMN_HISTORY_UNREAD_NUM, 0);
    String whereClause = String.format("%s = %d", COLUMN_HISTORY_SENDER_ID,
            senderID);
    database.update(TABLE_HISTORY, result, whereClause, null);
    database.close();
}
```

I dont know what is "٢٠٦٦١٤٨" and why does it appear? But i use google translate: ٢٠٦٦١٤٨ = 2066148. 2066148 is my senderID. 
How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this database.update(TABLE_HISTORY, result, COLUMN_HISTORY_SENDER_ID + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(senderID) });

Comment: You shouldn't translate **numbers**.

Comment: why would you ever use `String.format()` for an SQL statement?

Answer (score 2):

`String.format` uses the user's default locale, which might not be appropriate for SQL (as you've seen).

Either specify a proper locale explicitly:

```
whereClause = String.format(Locale.US, "%s = %d", COLUMN_HISTORY_SENDER_ID, senderID);
```

or don't use `format`:

```
whereClause = COLUMN_HISTORY_SENDER_ID + " = " + senderID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. DON'T USE STRING.FORMAT IN SQL STATEMENT.

I use

```
database.update(TABLE_HISTORY, result, COLUMN_HISTORY_SENDER_ID
            + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(senderID) });
```

It work perfect!